# changing Datasource of Kendoui Multiselect at runtime

Tags: kendo-ui, multi-select

I would like to bind data to a kendoui multiselect at runtime.
for example suppose that I want to bind it as a cascade of a drobdownlist.
any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<p>
    <label for="categories">Catergories:</label>

    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
        .Name("categories")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
        .OptionLabel("Select category...")
        .DataTextField("CategoryName")
        .DataValueField("CategoryId")
        .DataSource(source =>
        {
            source.Read(read =>
            {
                read.Action("GetCascadeCategories", "CoreParam");
            });
        })
        .Events(e =>e.Select("select"))
    )

</p>
<p>
    <label for="parameters">Parameters:</label>

    @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
        .Name("parameters")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:400px" })
        .DataTextField("ParamDesc")
        .DataValueField("ParamCode")
        .Placeholder("Select products...")
        .DataSource(source =>
        {
            source.Read(read =>
            {
                read.Action("GetCascadeParams", "CoreParam")
                    .Data("filterParams");
            })
            .ServerFiltering(true);
        })
        .AutoBind(false)
    )

</p>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function filterParams() {
        return {
            categories: $("#categories").val()
        };
    }

    function select(e) {
        var dropdownlist = $("#categories").data("kendoDropDownList");
        dropdownlist.select(e.item.index());
        var multiselect = $("#parameters").data("kendoMultiSelect");
        multiselect.dataSource.read();
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom MVVM binder which will get the text of the dropdownlist and will set a property of the ViewModel. This property can be bound to the hidden field. Check out the link below  for more information.

Comment: you know I just need a way to trigger Read method of datasource delegate which I use to bound the multiselect. but I donno how can I do this.